# How do I inspect a BroadcastChannel with Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, broadcast-channel

Is there a way, with Chrome DevTools, to see what’s going on in a `BroadcastChannel` other than attaching a `message` event listener to it, so that I could see who’s `postMessage`-ing what?

Comment: No, there is none.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I found was extending the prototype of `postMessage` like this:

```
(function(postMessage) {
  BroadcastChannel.prototype.postMessage = function (message) {
    debugger;

    postMessage.call(this, message);
  };
}(BroadcastChannel.prototype.postMessage));
```

You can obviously replace the `debugger` statement by something else like `console.trace(message)` for example, than you get the callstack directly printed in the console.

I hopes this helps you.